# Проблема с импортом

Tags: javascript, импорт

Всем привет!

Есть константа, которая лежит в отдельном файле с другими подобными, условно выглядит так:

```
export const BASE_URL = 'https://example.com/';
```

Я хочу использовать эту переменную в другом файле который делает module.exports

```
module.exports = {
    siteUrl: BASE_URL,
    generateRobotsTxt: true,
    autoLastmod: false
}
```

**Можно ли как то импортировать такую переменную?**

Импортирование через `import {BASE_URL } from ''` не работает, а создать отдельный файл и экспортировать переменную тоже через module.exports возможности нет :).

Comment: Что значит "Импортирование через import {BASE_URL } from '' не работает"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего вы пишете серверный код на NodeJS. А Node не поддерживает импорты ES6 по дефолту.
*(можно изменить тип пакета на `module` и тогда будет поддержка `import`, но это уже совсем другая история. подробнее в документации: [тут](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html))*

Решение такое: в файле, из которого нужно экспортировать переменную, поменяйте экспорт на модульный:

```
module.exports = 'https://example.com/';
```

И потом импортируйте в другом файле через `require`:

```
const BASE_URL = require('filename')
```